# What is the correct/best/most efficient way to use centralised version control?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I work as part of a small development team (4 people).

None of us are incredibly experienced with version control, but we are required to use Perforce under our company's policies. For the most part it has been great, but we have have kept to a simple process agreed between ourselves that is starting to become less ideal. I was wondering if people could share their experiences of version control working smoothly and efficiently.

Our original setup is this:

- We have a trunk, which holds production code as it is now.
- Each user creates a development branch for their work, as we have
  always worked on separate areas that don't really affect each other.
- We develop on Redhat Linux boxes and the code is run from /var/www/html. So we sync to a workspace and copy those files to this path, change the permissions and then perform our changes there. When we want to check in, we check out the files in the workspace, overwrite them with what we have changed and submit (I think this might be our weakest part)
- Any changes to trunk will be incorporated if they affect the functionality in question. The code is then deployed for testing.
- When testing is complete, we merge the branch into trunk, and then create a release branch from the current trunk this is tested again and then released into production.

This worked fine previously because our projects were small and very separated. Now, however, we are all working on the same big dev branch. Changes have been released since the creation of the dev branch, and more will be made before it is finished.

We are also required to deploy the code for testing in various stages of it's development, and this code needs to be up to date with both the development changes, and any changes that have been made to production.

We have decided at this stage that we will create the release branch at the same time as the dev branch, into which we will merge current Trunk(production) and the current dev branch each time we need a testing version so that it is completely up to date. However, this merge takes a lot of time from the whole team and isn't really working out too well.

I've been told that different teams have different ways of going about things so I'm not looking for a fix for my process, but I would love to hear what setup you use of your willing to share

Comment: Too broad: whole books (I can recommend *[Software Configuration Management Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Software-Configuration-Management-Patterns-Integration/dp/0201741172/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404725676&sr=1-1&keywords=software+configuration+management+patterns)*) have been written on the topic. There is far too much to cover for a [SO] answer. One issue is the way you use VC is, to a large extent, determined by your development process: VC is one tool amongst many to support building and maintaining systems.

Comment: I'm not really looking for help in designing my process or anything. As I said,  I'm just looking to see what processes are used by others. If yours or someone else's is too complicated to summarise like I did, that's fine

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation though, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not particularly familiar with version control and best practices I would suggest utilizing Streams in Perforce.  Functionally Streams and Branches are very similar.  The difference with Streams is that Perforce utilizes pre-built relationships based on the stream type and gives basic governance (i.e. you can't copy those files to the other stream until you merge).

All the commands CAN be overridden by an admin.

Once you are utilizing streams you can do things a few different ways.  You have three types of streams, Release (most stable), Main (stable), and Development (least stable).  You can create any hierarchy you like.

I suppose in your case I would have a Mainline, an integration development stream, and then a development stream for each developer to utilize.  That way you each have your own playground and can move your changes to the integration stream once they are complete.  Those completed changes can then be merged down to the other developer streams.